# Node Webkit - Fire Event from iframe to the app

Tags: javascript, events, iframe, browser, node-webkit

I'm trying to make a mini kiosk browser (fullscreen, minimum option, etc) using nodewebkit.
The kiosk browser is strutured like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <!-- placeholder until iframe is loaded -->
    <div class="placeholder">
        <div class="loading">Loading</div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="" nwfaketop nwdisable></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Basic features of the kiosk browser
        document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
            //Toggle FullScreen on F1 or F11
            if (evt.keyCode == 112 || evt.keyCode == 122) {
                win.toggleKioskMode();
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
        loadIframe();
        ...
    </script>
</body>
```

The problem is, once the iframe is loaded and displayed (100% width and height) the event are fired in this iframe and not in my app.

I've tried several things using the [documentation](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Mini-browser-in-iframe) but I didn't really understand how to make things work the way I want.

So any help would be great ! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way by using [`document-end`](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Window#document-end) listener which is fired when window or a child iframe is loaded (just before the onload event).

```
win.on('document-end', function(frame) {
    if(frame != null){ // If frame is not the window but an Iframe
        frame.contentDocument.body.addEventListener('keydown', yourScript);
    }
});
```

Maybe not the proper way to do it but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can register your event handler in iframe's content window as soon as the iframe loads.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
iframe.onload = function(){
   iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('keydown',yourHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable some communication between iframe and you window then you can use [prothole](http://ternarylabs.github.io/porthole/) . Do note that you may need access to the other domain which is serving the iframe too.Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not an classic web app so I think there is a way in node-webkit to do that without having access to the other domain. Because the point of my "kiosk app" is to load any website.
Nodewebkit provide a way to inject javascript in iframe (using [window.eval()](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Window#windowevalframe-script) ) but I don't really understand how to use it.